# creating memory of the size of a pointer for char array inside struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I have a program that asks to input two arguments using `argv` and I would like to then using the length of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` dynamically allocate memory for two pointers to `char` inside my `struct` equal to the size of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Here is my code but I'm not sure if I did it correctly, can anyone verify? Parameters `passedargv1` and `passedargv2` inside the function are `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` passed from the `main()` function. Basically I want to make `chararray1=argv[1]` and `chararray2=argv[2]` as if they were just plain `char` arrays, but I don't know ahead of time the size of our input so I can't pre-initialize `chararray2` and `chararray2`. Also, I can't change what is inside `argv`, so i cannot have `chararray1` and `chararray2` just point to them because I will need to change them later on.

```
struct StructInformation{

    char *chararray1;
    char *chararray2;
};



typedef struct StructInformation SimplifiedStruct;

SimplifiedStruct *CreateMem(char *passedargv1, char *passedargv2) {

SimplifiedStruct *ptr=(SimplifiedStruct*)malloc(sizeof(SimplifiedStruct));
ptr->chararray1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(passedargv1));
ptr->chararray2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(passedargv2));
```

Comment: This gets significantly simpler if you're on a POSIX or XOPEN compliant system with [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) *and* stop casting `malloc()` results

Comment: oh my bad i'll fix that thank you. But what about sizeof(passedargv1) is that okay or do i need to make it &passedargv1 because it is a pointer?

Comment: That doesn't work. sizeof(passedargv1) should be 4 or 8 byte (assuming a 32 or 64 bit system). Even when you dereference it, it wouldn't work since the sizeof() argument is calculated at compile time. As @WhozCraig suggested, strdup() is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't cast the return from `malloc()`
2. `malloc(char*)malloc` is obviously wrong.
3. For your main issue, `sizeof(passedargv1)` and `sizeof(passedargv2)` both just evaluate to `sizeof(char *)`, so no, you have not done it correctly. You'll need to call `strlen()` on your two arguments, and add `1` to each, that'll tell you how much memory you need to allocate, presuming you just want to copy in the strings.

For instance:

```
ptr->chararray1 = malloc(strlen(passedargv1) + 1);
ptr->chararray2 = malloc(strlen(passedargv2) + 1);
```

and then presumably:

```
strcpy(ptr->chararray1, passedargv1);
strcpy(ptr->chararray2, passedargv2);
```

Don't forget to check the return from `malloc()` to make sure you got your memory.

Comment: For 1. you mean (SimplifiedStruct*) and (char*)? I thought that was needed for type safety issues as creating memory doesn't know what type to return.
2. fixed, thank you.
3. so you mean i should do something like sizeof(strlen(passedargv1)+1)?

Comment: @user2778481: 1 - yes, that's what I mean. You've been misinformed. It's necessary in C++, and used to be necessary in C many years ago, but for modern C it's just bad, and hurts type safety rather than helps it. 3. Not quite, see edit.

Comment: Ah i understand, 1 char is 1 byte so it gives the correct memory space. Thank you.

Comment: @user2778481: Correct, `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: If i free the struct will the memory allocated from the two char pointers inside the struct also be freed or will i have to do that seperately?

Comment: @user2778481: You have to do it separately. It's often helpful to define a destructor function for structs like this, which `free()`s any dynamically allocated members, and then `free()`s the struct itself. That way (1) you can get rid of each struct with a single function call, instead of having to make 3 calls to `free()` each time; and (2) it means you never forget to `free()` the dynamically allocated members.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sizeof` with `strlen` and remember to include `string.h`. Because the size of a pointer always equals 4. And there is no need to use a `cast` when calling malloc.

```
ptr->chararray1 = malloc(strlen(passedargv1) + 1);
ptr->chararray2 = malloc(strlen(passedargv2) + 1);
```

EDIT:
Prototype of malloc:
`void* malloc (size_t size);`
It returns a pointer of `void*` which can be cast to the desired type of data pointer in order to be dereferenceable. Since you have already defined `chararray1` and `chararray2` as `char*`, casts can be omitted.

Comment: You need to add 1 for the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: The sizeof a pointer is not always 4. On 64 bit machines it's 8 and there may be even other exotic machines having different pointer sizes.

Comment: You actually do need to cast `void` pointers if you want to dereference them or access their members without the aid of a pointer variable of the correct type, I think this is what he means. For example, the cast is necessary in: `char * my_func(void * ptr) { return ((struct StructInformation *) ptr)->chararray1; }` even though it would be pretty silly to use a `void` pointer in the first place in this particular example.